# Undefined reference to my_load_defaults() upon migrating a MySQL client to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Upon C-compling and linking a MySQL client program to MariaDB on Debian I get a "undefined reference" to the my_load_defaults() function.

In MySQL the prototype is:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/8.0.0/my__default_8h.html

It looks like the library containing this function is missing or the name I use is wrong.

In the (MySQL) Makefile I use:
LIBS   = -L/usr/lib/mysql  -lmysqlclient

Where to find it?

Comment: It is not part of the API, is it? why should it be in the header files

Comment: so I found the function in the source of MariaDB in file:
https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.2/mysys/my_default.c

But which package in Debian to install to git the library available?

Comment: I filed a bug at Raspbian:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/raspbian/+bug/1713945